# Design: use independent or correlated status for parent and child

Tags: mysql, database-design, elasticsearch, architecture

This is a design question. 
there are two entities in our system: Campaign, Assignment. One campaign can be assigned to multiple users, thus resulting in multiple assignments. (can be tens of thousands). Think of it as 'TaskRabbit'. There is a 'status' field for both Campaign and Assignment.

Apparently, when campaign is 'paused', Assignment is also considered 'paused'. When campaign is 'ended', Assignment is also ended.

User need to filter their assignments by status, say finding out all ended assignments.

The question is,

1 )should I change assignment status to be 'paused'|'ended' when campaign is paused or ended? Pro is that it will be easy to do the filtering on assignments. Cons is that there can be potential 100k assignments for each campaign. Batch update their status according to campaign's status is not performant. In addition, the cache layer does not support batch update.

2) Or instead, make assignment ‘status’ totally independent of campaign status. Pro is that，now there is no need to batch update assignment upon campaign status change. Cons is that now for filtering, i will need to first get the ids of the campaign of filtered status, then do a second query to get corresponding assignment with extra condition: (campaign id in those filtered ids).

Any suggestions?

Comment: For option #2 - you don't need to do two queries, do just one query with a simple join: `SELECT a.status, ...... FROM Assignment a JOIN Campaign c ON a.id = c.assigment_id WHERE .....`

Comment: Can a campaign have no assignments? Can a campaign be paused without assignments also being paused. Can a campaign progress when one or more of its assignments is paused?

Comment: @kordirko, that only works for MySql. We get assignments from ES. The paged query against MySql is relatively slow due to large amount of rows in the assignment table.

Comment: @Strawberry, yes, a campaign can have no assignments. (no one takes this task). Whether campaign is paused is independent of whether assignments being paused.  A campaign can progress when one or more of its assignments are paused.

Comment: So the answer is 2 (with indexes). I don't know what elastic search is, but clearly, all the data needs to be in the RDBMS

Answer (score 0):

Can you change the way you see the system?

> Apparently, when campaign is 'paused', Assignment is also considered
>   'paused'.

Can you regard is_paused property of the Assignment as the activity of the relation? So that if Assignment is paused, it is regarded like temporarily deleted.

In this case when you pause Campaign, you should not propagate this paused status to all Assignments, because the link still stays active and just communicates Campaign state.

**UPDATE:**

I will expand a little on my answer now.

What I propose is to remove Assignment from system as an Entity. Of course I do not see the system from inside like you do, but it looks, like there are only two Entities in your system: `User` and `Campaign`. The Assignment is only a N:1 relation from Campaign to User, right?

This relation is not itself an entity, but at database level it will be stored at the separate `campaign_to_user` table with (user_id, campaign_id) columns. But may be your ORM system allows to define relation attributes like Laravel Eloquent does? So, that table will actually look like (user_id, campaign_id, active).

When you query for `User`'s `Campaign`'s, you perform select on campaign_to_user table with `WHERE active = TRUE`.

That, I believe, solves the problem with status updates. If you want to disable a specific Campaign of a specific User, you manipulate that `active` attribute and your ORM does the job. If you disable Campaign in total, all User links are active, but the Campaign is shut down.

Comment: Vlad, do you mean adding is_paused property for assignment? So searching paused assignment includes getting assignments belong to a paused campaign, or is_paused = true?

Comment: @user648922 Updated my answer with some clarification.